# Wordpress 3.5 - Add custom image size

Tags: thumbnails, images

Since the new version of Wordpress (3.5), it seems to be an incompatibility between the image manager and the custom image sizes.

Previously I used in my functions.php :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'addemo_setup' ); 

function addemo_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );   
    add_image_size( 'featured-image', 375, 500, true );  
}

// Insert Custom Sized Image Into Post Using Media Gallery
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'custom_image_sizes_choose' );  
function custom_image_sizes_choose( $sizes ) {  
    $custom_sizes = array(  
        'featured-image' => 'Featured Image'  
    );  
    return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );  
}
```

When I add a thumbnail, I don't have any choice.

Does anyone has encountered this problem ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, can you elaborate?

Comment: When you add a thumbnail you can choose the size you want (amongst the defaults one or the sizes you added). It's No longer possible.

Comment: Is your image bigger than 375x500?  I don't think WordPress scales images up, just down, so only the options smaller than your original image are available for selection.

Comment: Do you get any relevant PHP / Javascript exceptions?

Comment: none :) I fixed it with a good plugin, check my update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the functions.php to add my custom image size, I installed the plugin [Simple Image Size](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/). This plugin does perfectly the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can pest following code in function.php.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop);
add_image_size('Home Top', 120, 120, true);
add_image_size('Home bottom', 270, 90, false);
add_image_size('Archive thumb', 150, 75, true);
add_image_size('Special', 397, 224, true);
add_image_size( 'Test cropped', 500, 500, true );

function sgr_display_image_size_names_muploader( $sizes ) {

    $new_sizes = array();

    $added_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    foreach( $added_sizes as $key => $value) {
        $new_sizes[$value] = $value;
    }

    // This preserves the labels in $sizes, and merges the two arrays
    $new_sizes = array_merge( $new_sizes, $sizes );

    return $new_sizes;
}
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'sgr_display_image_size_names_muploader', 11, 1);
```

This code worked for me in wordpress3.5.

Regards
Onkar Kubal

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works after activating the extension "extension=php_gd2.dll" in the php.ini.